# Confusing Problems with LaTeX3/expl3 \pdftex_if_engine:TF Switch

Tags: pstricks, latex3, minted, expl3

For a number of days I've been confused with some problems I had when using the `\pdftex_if_engine:TF` switch in a `LaTeX3/expl3` class of my own. I thought it would be equivalent to the `\ifpdf` switch, but I've found quite a different behavior from one to the other with regard to the `minted` package and to polar coordinates-based nodes in `PSTricks`. To be more precise, in the second case I had PostScript errors precluding the generation of graphics including nodes defined in terms of polar coordinates when using the `LaTeX3` switch. The strangest thing to me was that changing to the `LaTeX2e` switch got everything right without needing to use the `\ExplSyntax(Off|On)` switch at all.

My reason for this post is that I thought it might be useful to have somebody explaining why this different behavior -- or pointing to relevant documentation --,  and that  knowing about this effect might help other package/class developers who are eager of using `LaTeX3/expl3`. I'm aware of [Frank Mittelbach's sound advice in a comment to this linked post](/questions/130485/conflict-between-geometry-ratio-setting-keys-and-expl3-syntax) with regard to switching off the `expl3` syntax when loading `LaTeX2e` packages, but in this case it was just about the engine switch.

Comment: `\pdftex_if_engine:TF` just checks the engine used, which is pdfTeX for both `pdflatex` and `latex`. It will evaluate false if XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX are used. In order to check for PDF output you still need to use `\ifpdf`.

Comment: @egreg: But I got my ``PSTricks`` graphics right if they did not have nodes defined in terms of polar coordinates. I guess there must be something else going on. Or, does your comment explain this "partial sensitivity"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three engines in use: `pdftex`, `luatex` and `xetex`. Both `pdftex` and `luatex` can be used for getting either PDF or DVI output, by calling them
`pdflatex` or `lualatex` (for PDF output) and `latex` or `dvilualatex` (for DVI output).

If the engine is `pdftex`, independently if the call is `pdflatex` or `latex`, `\pdftex_if_engine:TF` evaluates to true, as `expl3` macros are “output agnostic”. Similarly, `\luatex_if_engine:TF` evaluates to true with either `lualatex` or `dvilualatex`.

You still need `\ifpdf` for a check about the output.

It's possible to define an `expl3` conditional based on `ifpdf`:

```
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \output_if_pdf: { p, T, F, TF }
 {
  \ifpdf \prg_return_true: \else: \prg_return_false: \fi:
 }
```

which will make available the “predicate” form `\output_if_pdf_p:` and the usual boolean functions `\output_if_pdf:TF`, `\output_if_pdf:T` and `\output_if_pdf:TF`

Comment: Though without understanding entirely yet the behavior I observed when compiling with my ``expl3`` class using the ``LaTeX3`` engine switch, now I understand much better what is going on in the relationship between the different engines and the output format. Thx for enhancing your original comment in the form of an answer.

Comment: @Marcos perhaps one additional comment here: as egreg explained these commands test which "engine" is used and the reason for having them is that different engines provide different primitives (sometimes the same functionality is done differently, sometims a certain functionality is only available in a specific engine). So they are there to allow the kernel (or a package to built some low-level support code  in a different way depending on which engine actually runs. Perhaps they should have been marked "internal" but we anticipated that some packages may be written that only work with say lua

Comment: @egreg: Oh, and thx for the new custom conditional. I'll put it to good use ;-)

Comment: @Frank Mittelbach: An insightful addition in a few words. Thanks so much, again.